# Argand diagram problem

Tags: complex-numbers

Why is the point **P** is removed? Please help.
[image]

Comment: Please only include relevant part in image. I started reading whole page and saw then that question was only about P.

Comment: @KingTut:  Perhaps the Question here is motivated by locating $P$ away from the origin, so while ostensibly it is "only about $P$", the problem is motivated by the application involving the relation between the "angle of elevation" and the (directed) line segment $PQ$.  It would be good to have more clarification, certainly.

Comment: Hardmath . The development following the diagram has to me nothing to do with why P is included or excluded. Just i was saying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $P=2i$ is removed because if you plug it in to the function $z-2i$ you get $0$, which doesn't have an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you relate complex numbers to vectors, substituting for $P$ in the $\arg ()$ we get $0$ or a null vector. Since a null vector does not have any direction, its argument is not defined.